# h2o cluster comes up successfully, but web ui won't work

Tags: hadoop, sandbox, hortonworks-data-platform, h2o

I am trying to instal h20 on hortonworks sandbox 2.4 by following http://www.h2o.ai/download/h2o/hadoop. Everything runs well, I see the messages
"Blocking until the H2O cluster shuts down..." and "open h2o web flow through 10.0.2.15:54321".
But when I go to that page, it is not loaded giving ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error. 
What should I do to connect h2o web page?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like it could be an issue with using a private vs public IP.  See if you can `ping 10.0.2.5`.  If that is getting a timeout then the machine is not reachable. If you can indeed reach the machine then see if you can reach the service: `wget http://10.0.2.15:54321`

Comment: I can't ping to10.0.2.15 from my computer

Comment: I tried port forwarding using NAT, but it does not work. How can I access from my computer to 10.0.2.15 @Erin

Comment: This is more of a networking question, sorry I can't be of more help.  This shows how to reach localhost if it's not accessible, perhaps you can try the same for your 10.0.2.15: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/6227/sandbox-1270018080-not-accessible.html

Comment: Thanks for your helps. This problem was because of incompatibility of my sandbox and h2o version. @Erin